# Jquery Play sound only once

Tags: jquery, ajax, notifications, audio

I need jQuery to play a notification sound when the user gets a new message. Here is my code with the count of unread messages and sound. The problem is when the user receives a new message it plays sound every .1 sec until he reads it. I need it to play only once, and again when the user receives another message.

```
    function pullNewMessageCount() {
                    var url = 'messenger/bubble.php';
                    $.ajax({
                        url: url,
                        dataType: 'html',
                        type: 'POST',
                        success: function(latestCount) {
                            setTimeout('pullNewMessageCount()', 200);
                            $('#bub').html(latestCount);
                            if (latestCount > 0)
                            { 
                                $('#bub').removeClass('hidden').addClass('bubble').addClass('animating');
playSound('message');
                            } else if ((latestCount = $('#bub').html()) && (latestCount > 0)) {
                                $('#bub').removeClass('animating');                              
                            } else if ((latestCount = '0') || (!latestCount)) {
                                $('#bub').removeClass('bubble').addClass('hidden');
                            } else {
                                $('#bub').removeClass('bubble').addClass('hidden');
                            }
                        },
                        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: What's the function playSound's definition? Is the function pullNewMessageCount() executed once, or every 0.1 seconds?

Comment: Every 0.1 second. function playSound(filename){   
                document.getElementById("bub").innerHTML='<audio autoplay="autoplay"><source src="./sounds/' + filename + '.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" /><source src="./sounds/' + filename + '.ogg" type="audio/ogg" /><embed hidden="true" autostart="true" loop="false" src="./sounds/'+ filename +'.mp3" /></audio>';

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the latestCount value, and only play the sound when the latestCount is lower than the current count, instead of always when > 0.

When new messages are available, the latestCount will again be lower than the current count, causing the sound to play again.

Comment: How can I store it? I think it will reset variables in every call of function.

Comment: You can store it in a hidden field on the page: <input id=LatestCount" type="hidden" /> and assign and read the value with Javascript.